# problems with the ray in projectPixelTo3dRay

Tags: ros, image-geometry

[image: Rosanswers logo]

According to the API, the return value is "the unit vector in the camera coordinate frame in the direction of rectified pixel" (from 1.4 is not unit, but with unit z component).
I expected that multiplying such a vector by a scalar z would give me the 3D point with depth z that projects into the input pixel. However, when i back-project such a vector the result is not the input pixel:

```
cv::Point2d pixel(r,c);
cv::Point3d ray =  model.projectPixelTo3dRay(pixel);
cv::Point3d point = ray * z;
cv::Point2d back_pixel = model.project3dToPixel(point);
```

I would expect back_pixel be equal to pixel for any z, but it only happens for z=1. Have I misunderstood something?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9882/problems-with-the-ray-in-projectpixelto3dray/) by [Javier Romero](https://answers.ros.org/users/466/javier-romero/) on ROS Answers with karma: 66 on 2011-05-03

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

OK, it's pretty straightforward if you look at the code of the functions. The problem is that I was looking to the second camera of a stereo pair, and therefore the components Tx is non-zero.
Therefore you have to make a couple of translations:

```
cv::Point2d pixel(r,c);
cv::Point3d ray =  model.projectPixelTo3dRay(pixel);
float tx_fx = model.Tx()/model.fx();
cv::Point3d point(z*(ray.x+tx_fx)-tx_fx,z*ray.y,z*ray.z);
cv::Point2d back_pixel = model.project3dToPixel(point);
```

---

Originally posted by [Javier Romero](https://answers.ros.org/users/466/javier-romero/) with karma: 66 on 2011-05-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3